# When I Type "Ctrl + Shift + T" in java-editor in Eclipse it shows <ul></ul>

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

Normally when I type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> in Eclipse it opens up thee "Open Type"-dialog. Somehow this behaviour has changed. Now, when I type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> it adds `<ul></ul>` to the current file I'm editing.

How can I change this behaviour, so it will open the "Open Type"-dialog?

I'm using Eclipse 3.4.2 on Windows XP.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to:
Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys and scroll down till you find "Open Type".
Then you can re-add the shortcut, or if you don't have custom shortcuts you can simply restore to defaults.

Comment: It was still there but somehow the command "Lists: Bullet List"-command also had the same binding. After removing that binding, everything was working fine. Thank you.

Comment: @MarcelSchutte - It quite often happens that new plug-ins, or plug-in updates change or add key bindings. These can show in the problems view as *duplicate* key bindings. Deleting the binding can just result in it coming back the next time that plug-in is updated, so I tend to change the key binding to something I'm unlikely to hit by accident in stead. And yes, having the Ctrl+Shift+T binding disabled in particular is incredibly irritating.